# Shell Scripting : (standard_in): illegal character: T and (standard_in) 2: parse error

Tags: shell, sh, bc

I am trying to perform addition of values using

```
Total_time=`echo "$Time_clone+$Time_push+$Time_fetch+$Time_pull" | bc`
```

which is throwing below error when I am running the script

```
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: T
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 2: illegal character: T
(standard_in) 2: parse error
```

Comment: before this command, append echo $Time_clone " " $Time_push .. each parameters. these numerical variables?

Comment: Yes, Time_clone is 0.29 , push is .59 , pull is 3.28 and fetch is 0.11

Comment: What is the LC_NUMERIC parameter in locale command